# Possible to install APK from personal website?

Tags: apk, side-loading

How can I allow a user to do web-install of Android APK file from my personal web page? Like to create a personal (private) APK repository where I could put APK files and send a client the link to the APK file. A client would then click on this file and install the Android app to its phone.

Is this possible/allowed on the first place?

Any cool tool a user should use for installing such apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this can be done with Aptoide server and the same Android app for client.

On server side you just copy all APKs and generate the XML file via Aptoide server script. User then installs this app, adds your repository and downloads/installs the APK.

Comment: As @askmoo said a good option is to use Aptoide [http://www.aptoide.com/index2.html] with this option your clients will have an application like Market that will allow them to install your applications

Answer (score 3):

Once the user allows `Unknown Sources`, they should pretty much be able to get APK from anywhere...
Check this StackOverflow question: [Hosting an .apk file on over own site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6211416/70482)

Comment: When I use mobile browser to access the APK file located on my server, it downloads it rather than installing it directly. And yes, the Unknown Sources is checked.

Comment: Now open a file manager on the device, locate the file and try to open it -- it will launch through the installer.

Comment: I know this. This way or via ADB is not complicated for me :). But it is for some of my clients. Is there a way to install it like on the Market - click on install and app is installed?

Comment: @askmoo no, that's not possible afaik

Comment: @askmoo: Not without having a cooperating app already installed in the phone; and that's a Good Thing - unless you want to revisit the Browser Dark Ages (early 2000s), when just visiting a malicious page would auto-install a boatload of malware to your computer.

Comment: Is there a way to install like Apple Enterprise account?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to download and install the application just like they can on market, the user must be using the stock browser. Otherwise, they must have specific plug-ins when using other browsers.

> When I use mobile browser to access
>   the APK file located on my server, it
>   downloads it rather than installing it
>   directly. And yes, the Unknown Sources
>   is checked

Are you using the stock browser?